# How to remove and create log in Windows Event Viewer

Tags: c#, event-log, event-viewer

I have an app. I'm trying to write log in `Windows Event Viewer` when its crashing. I found [Write to Windows Application Event Log](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25725151/write-to-windows-application-event-log) and I'm using `DispatcherUnhandledExceptionEventHandler` for catching unhandled exception. I'm setting it in constructor of app like:

```
 DispatcherUnhandledException += MyApplication_DispatcherUnhandledException;
```

and write log like this:

```
using (EventLog eventLog = new EventLog("Application"))
        {
            eventLog.Source = "Application";
            eventLog.WriteEntry(exceptionMessage, EventLogEntryType.Error);
        }
```

Log creates, but in `Run` method of `System.Windows.Application` occurs another exception and windows adds this error in Event Viewer with another Id, source....

```
Description: The process was terminated due to an unhandled exception.
```

> Exception Info: System.Exception
>      at ServerApp.MainWindow..ctor()
>
> Exception Info: System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException
>      at System.Windows.Markup.WpfXamlLoader.Load(System.Xaml.XamlReader, System.Xaml.IXamlObjectWriterFactory, Boolean, System.Object, System.Xaml.XamlObjectWriterSettings, System.Uri)
>      at System.Windows.Markup.WpfXamlLoader.LoadBaml(System.Xaml.XamlReader, Boolean, System.Object, System.Xaml.Permissions.XamlAccessLevel, System.Uri)
>      at System.Windows.Markup.XamlReader.LoadBaml(System.IO.Stream, System.Windows.Markup.ParserContext, System.Object, Boolean)
>      at System.Windows.Application.LoadBamlStreamWithSyncInfo(System.IO.Stream, System.Windows.Markup.ParserContext)
>      at System.Windows.Application.LoadComponent(System.Uri, Boolean)
>      at System.Windows.Application.DoStartup()

How can I write only my log in event viewer?

Comment: looks like your event handler is not handling that exception. could it be that this exception is thrown before the handler for the unhandled exceptions is added?

Comment: Did you create a new event log like in CodeCoaster answer?

Comment: Try commenting out that `using` block. It looks to me as if you have an unhandled exception.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;

...
...

public void WriteToEventLog(EventLogEntryType eventLogType, string message, string logSourceName)
{
    if (!EventLog.SourceExists(logSourceName))
    {
        EventLog.CreateEventSource(logSourceName, "Application");
    }
    using (var eventLog = new EventLog { Source = logSourceName })
    {
        const int maxLength = 31000;
        if (message.Length > maxLength)
        {
            message = message.Substring(0, maxLength);
        }
        eventLog.WriteEntry(message, eventLogType);
    }
}
```

The user, under which account this app is going to run, needs to have access to be able to create logs.

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

I would put a try catch around the whole process and then write the exception to a file 
see:

[how to save exception in txt file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21307789/how-to-save-exception-in-txt-file)

You don't have to always write to the file but just to understand what is really going on